# ¿Cómo traer el primer dato de cada grupo?

Tags: oracle, sql

Buen día colegas

Tengo una consulta, quiero traer los datos, sin que se repitan de un **modelo**, ese modelo tiene varios **( id )** pero solo quiero traer el primer **id** de cada modelo. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de como realizar esta acción?.

Por ahora estoy usando `DISTINCT` me funciona, para que los modelos no se repitan pero ahora quiero el primer id de cada modelo.

consulta usada:

```
SELECT DISTINCT modelo,id
           FROM ITT_ALP_GLOBAL 
           WHERE LINEA='Comercial'
           order by modelo asc
```

[image: Consulta SQL]

Comment: No queda claro. El primer submodelo de cada modelom ¿dónde están los submodelos?

Comment: @F.bernal Perdón por no aclarar el id= submodelo. solo quiero el primer id de cada modelo :'(

Comment: @NaCl ¿tienes alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: que es primer id de cada modelo? en una base de datos, no existe una relacion entre primero y ultimo, los datos no se guardan como primero y ultimo (por mas que la base siempre haga el select igual y escupa los datos igual, esto en realidad no se puede asegurar)

Comment: Te sirve el primer `id` en orden alfabético?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Por supuesto.

Comment: estoy esperando el min con el group by de @PatricioMoracho ;)

Comment: @gbianchi, ahora me da verguenza ;-)

Comment: Bue hombre que es una respuesta trivial tardamos mas tiempo en darsela por verguenza entre los dos y lo hacemos esperar... :p

Comment: @gbianchi, ahi, va, voy a ver si le agrego un poco más de info.

Comment: Yo aclararia que no hay un concepto de primero y ultimo en una base de datos. Habria que hacer una pregunta canonica al respecto, hay muchas preguntas en ese sentido.

Comment: @gbianchi El primer dato de cada grupo en forma Ascendente, el primer id de cada modelo. Eso es mi pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar como menciona el compañero @gbianchi, decir primero y último en base de datos es relativo, relativo al orden que tenga la consulta. Podría ser que el `primero` signifique el más antiguo, pero en este caso no tenemos una fecha ni un `id` incremental para determinarlo. Como te sirve que `primero` sea efectivamente el primero tomando un orden alfabético, lo que buscas  se resuelve simplemente usando una función de agregación, en este caso [`MIN()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions087.htm). ¿Qué significa una función de agregación? es una función que se aplica sobre una determinada columna dentro del grupo. Veamos tu caso:

```
SELECT  modelo, 
        MIN(id) ID
        FROM ITT_ALP_GLOBAL 
        WHERE LINEA='Comercial'
    GROUP BY modelo
    ORDER BY modelo ASC;
```

Nota: Si quieres tener el último de cada grupo, obviamente podrías usar un `MAX()`

Comment: Si me funciona. Pero  a la hora de ver los id los ordené por modelo quedando así: `SELECT  modelo, 
        MIN(id) ID
        FROM ITT_ALP_GLOBAL 
        WHERE LINEA='Comercial'
    GROUP BY modelo
    ORDER BY modelo asc`